# objective-c, animation block randomization

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an app with multiple animations that are simple, just an image moving from offscreen to onscreen and then back offscreen. I'm using animation blocks, and the code is like this:

```
void (^animationOne) (void) = ^{imageOne.center = d;};
void (^afterOne) (BOOL) = ^(BOOL f) {imageOne.center = dOrig;};
[UIView animateWithDuration:.85 delay:3 options:opts animations:animationOne completion:afterOne];
```

There are several others that more or less follow the same format. However, I'd like the order in which they appear to be random. Part of the problem is that both the animations and completion blocks are specific to one another, and are required, so I can't just stick the animations in an array, shuffle it, and then use the array for the animations. Is there a way for me to randomize this using the animation blocks, and if not, is there a different way I can do this so that I can randomize the order? Thanks.

Edit: Thanks to some helpful suggestions from vikingosegundo, I've altered my code to look like this:

```
 NSArray *animationsCompletions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:anim1,@"animation",after1, @"completion", nil],
                                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:anim2,@"animation",after2, @"completion", nil],
                                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:anim3,@"animation",after3, @"completion", nil],
                                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:anim4,@"animation",after4, @"completion", nil],
                                   nil];

NSDictionary *animationCompletionPair = [animationsCompletions randomElement];


[UIView animateWithDuration:.85 delay:3 options:opts animations:[animationCompletionPair objectForKey:@"animation"] completion:[animationCompletionPair objectForKey:@"completion"]];
[UIView animateWithDuration:.85 delay:8 options:opts animations:[animationCompletionPair objectForKey:@"animation"] completion:[animationCompletionPair objectForKey:@"completion"]];
[UIView animateWithDuration:.85 delay:13 options:opts animations:[animationCompletionPair objectForKey:@"animation"] completion:[animationCompletionPair objectForKey:@"completion"]];
[UIView animateWithDuration:.85 delay:18 options:opts animations:[animationCompletionPair objectForKey:@"animation"]completion:[animationCompletionPair objectForKey:@"completion"]];
```

However, now I'm receiving a Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when the view with the animations tries to load, and no other information is given by the compiler. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick the animation and completion blocks in an array (or two). Instead of shuffling the array, just pick indices at random and execute the corresponding animation blocks.

For example, using two arrays:

```
NSArray *animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:animation1, animation2, animation3, nil];
NSArray *completions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:completion1, completion2, completion3, nil];
int i = arc4random() % 3;
[UIView animateWithDuration:.85
                      delay:3
                    options:opts
                  animation:[animations objectAtIndex:i]
                 completion:[completions objectAtIndex:i]];
```

If you want each animation to run only once, then create a second array of indices and initialize it with numbers from 0 to n-1. Then shuffle that array and iterate over it executing the animation for the index you find at each position.

Answer (score 1):

[Caleb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058091/objective-c-animation-block-randomization/8058115#8058115) is right, but you should consider of using a [category method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html) on NSArray to get a random element, just to avoid code repetition and re-use tested code.

A `[array randomElement];` could be like this:

```
-(id)randomElement
{
    if ([self count] < 1) return nil;
    NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [self count];
    return [self objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
}
```

You will find this implementation and other convenient tools on NSArray in my [arraytools](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/arraytools/).

In this case the array would be filled with both, animations and completions block as pairs.

```
NSArray *animationsCompletions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:animation1,@"animation",completion1, @"completion", nil],
                                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:animation2,@"animation",completion2, @"completion", nil],
                                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:animation3,@"animation",completion3, @"completion", nil],
                                    nil];


NSDictionary *animationCompletionPair = [animationsCompletions randomElement];

[UIView animateWithDuration:.85
                      delay:3
                    options:opts
                  animation:[animationCompletionPair objectForKey:@"animation"]
                 completion:[animationCompletionPair objectForKey:@"completion"]];
```

Comment: okay, I'll try this and report back as to whether or not it works, thanks! :)

Comment: Of course, to connect an animation and a completion with this code u should collect one animation and one completion in one collection and put this into the array.

Comment: don't I want to assign each animation/completion a specific key instead of just using the same key for all of them?

Comment: you can use the same key, as u are using it in different dictionary.

Comment: and as the order of the animationsCompletions array is not ordered, the index of the pairs stay the same, so you can still do `[animationsCompletions objectAtIndex:1]`, if u want the second pair.

Comment: it's giving me a "Program received signal: SIBABRT" error on the line where I try to use the animation:[animationCompletionPair objectForKey:@"animation"]. before running, the compiler warns me that NSArray may not respond to "-objectForKey". any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: An array has no method objectForKey. A dictionary has.

Comment: And yet another error: I used `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys` without nil-sentinel. Fixed.

Comment: I've fixed all of the things you've listed and it's still not working; it gives a "Program received EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on the line where it's supposed to load the view controller in which all of the animations take place, but the compiler isn't giving me a whole lot of other information. I've edited my post with the code as it currently stands, but I'm not really sure what could be going wrong.